# Why JSONDecoder always returns nil for an optional property?

Tags: json, swift, urlsession

I get JSON one of the keys in which can be `nil`. So, I use an optional property in the data model, but after decoding, I always get `nil` for this property, even if in JSON the value by key contained a string and not `nil`. Below is the response I get and the output to the console, where I check what value is written to the `profilePath` property

**Response:**

> {"adult":false,"gender":2,"id":544002,"known_for_department":"Acting","name":"Giulio Berruti","original_name":"Giulio Berruti","popularity":2.467,**"profile_path":"/ktPKniWGVkm6eBG7a2R7WGd96kZ.jpg"**,"cast_id":1,"character":"Gabriel Emerson","credit_id":"5fdad9cfeda4b70041400df3","order":1},{"adult":false,"gender":0,"id":2897282,"known_for_department":"Acting","name":"Rhett Wellington","original_name":"Rhett Wellington","popularity":0.6,**"profile_path":null**,"cast_id":2,"character":"Simon Talbot","credit_id":"5fdad9dd3f7e1d004042f859","order":2}

**Console output:**

[image: console output]

```
func getMovieCredits(movieID: String, completion:@escaping (MovieCreditResponse) -> ()){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(movieID)/credits?api_key=<api_key>") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            print("JSON String: \(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))") //checking response
            let movies = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MovieCreditResponse.self, from: data!)
            
            for cast in movies.cast {
                print("Profile path - " + (cast.profilePath ?? "nil")) //checking profilePath property
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(movies )
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
```

```
struct MovieCreditResponse: Codable {
    let cast: [MovieCast]
}

struct MovieCast: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let character: String
    let name: String
    let profilePath: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in your JSON for `profilePath` property is `profile_path`. So you can simply set `keyDecodingStrategy` property of your `JSONDecoder` to `.convertFromSnakeCase` and the decoding will be correct:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
    let movies = try JSONDecoder().decode(MovieCreditResponse.self, from: data!)
} catch {
    // Handle error
    print(error)
}
```

Also, generally it's really bad practice to use `try!`. You should `do-try-catch` instead and handle any thrown errors.

Answer (score 1):

The property name in your JSON file is `profile_path`, but you try to decode it as `profilePath`.
You should add an enum to define JSON keys, like

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case profilePath = "profile_path"
    // add the other keys as well
}
```

Comment: it seems i tried this, the error appears: `Type 'MovieCast' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Comment: @Heimdallr this is also a valid solution. You just have to include all the missing properties of `MovieCast` struct as cases in the `CodingKeys` enum.